# JDBC ResultSet.getString Before/After Start/End of ResultSet Exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I have done a lot of searching about this topic through Google but I have yet to find someone using getString() in the way that I am using it so I have not been able to fix this issue in the normal ways that are suggested.

What I am trying to do is to obtain all of the information from the database and then use it to populate a table model within the program.  I do so by obtaining the data with getString and place it into a String[] object.  Here is my MySQLConnection class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MySQLConnect
{
    public MySQLConnect()
    {
        connect = null;
        statement = null;
        rSet = null;    
    }

    public void Connect(String dbase, String uname, String pword)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dbase , uname, pword);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection successful.  Please retry your submission." , "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);          
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }       
    }

    public void addDonor(int did, String dname, String dcname, int damount, DefaultTableModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            statement = connect.createStatement();

            statement.execute("Insert Into prg421_w5.donors Values ("+ did + ",'" + dname + "','" + dcname + "'," + damount + ")");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data entry added successfully." , "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            getRSet();
            updateTable(model);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void getRSet()
    {
        try 
        {
            rSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * From donors");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void updateTable (DefaultTableModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            for (i = getRowCount(); i > 0; i--)
            {
                model.removeRow(0);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        try
        {
            while (rSet.next())
            {
                String row[] = {rSet.getString("DonorName"),rSet.getString("DonorCharity"),((String)rSet.getString("DonationAmount"))};

                model.addRow(row);      
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }       
    }

    public int getRowCount()
    {
        try
        {
            rowCount = rSet.getInt(1);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return rowCount;
    }   

    public Boolean isConnected()
    {
        return connect != null;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        try
        {
          if (rSet != null)
          {
              rSet.close();
          }

          if (statement != null)
          {
              statement.close();
          }

          if (connect != null)
          {
              connect.close();
          }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e , "SQL Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }


    private Connection connect;
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet rSet;
    private int rowCount, i;

    private static Object o = null;
}
```

However I am always getting a dialog error message stating those error messages in the title:

Exception: Before start of result set

Exception: After end of result set

Here are the stack traces:

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2709)  at
>   MySQLConnect.getRowCount(MySQLConnect.java:100)   at
>   MySQLConnect.updateTable(MySQLConnect.java:68)    at
>   MySQLConnect.addDonor(MySQLConnect.java:42)   at
>   Operations.addDonor(Operations.java:135)  at
>   GUI$EventHandler.actionPerformed(GUI.java:145)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2709)  at
>   MySQLConnect.getRowCount(MySQLConnect.java:100)   at
>   MySQLConnect.updateTable(MySQLConnect.java:68)    at
>   Operations.updateTable(Operations.java:164)   at
>   GUI$EventHandler.actionPerformed(GUI.java:148)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

**The errors are actually being generated from the rSet.getInt(1); in my getRowCount() method.**

The data is still added and everything works correctly but it is just annoying to have to dismiss those message windows.  Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: can you please post more code and the StackTrace to see how the code behaves and explain you what kind of error/warning you're facing?

Comment: Write your complete code for the class.

Comment: Write complete stack trace of the error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call `rSet.next()` in getRowCount() before getting the result (and i don't even think you are creating the row count query anywhere in this code).

also, you are not closing your database resources before discarding them, which will cause resource leaks.  *always* close database resources in finally blocks as soon as you are finished with them.

Comment: I thought of this just now as well.  As for the closes they are there but only via the Close() method.  I do not want to close them down before I am finished with them.  The program continually waits for new data to be added but once the user clicks on the Exit button in another one of my classes I call Close.

Comment: @Geowil - everytime you re-assign the statement and rSet member variables, you are _losing a reference to a previous Statement/ResultSet_ (everytime you call `addDonor()` you create a new Statement and multiple new ResultSet instances).  when you do that, you are leaking resources.  you _must_ close them before you discard them

Answer (score 0):

I think you are positioning the cursor before the first row and then requesting data. You need to move the cursor to the first row.

```
 rSet.next();
 String foundType = rSet.getString(1);
```

It is common to do this in an if statement or loop.

```
if(rSet.next()){
   foundType = result.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasing a string as parameter to the ResultSet.getString("ColumnName");, could you try to pas the number of the column, as an int. starts to count @ 1.

```
ResultSet rs = getRSet();
if(rs != null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        String rows[] = { rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3) };
        model.add(rows);
    }
} //else, error handling
```

getString(int columnIndex) : returns String
"Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language."

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: The data is retrieved find, I had the wrong place denoted as the error point in my original posting.  The errors are actually coming from the getRowCount method.